# Best way to change routes loading order

Tags: symfony, routes, symfony4

I have routes in my controller loaded in /config/routes/annotations.yaml

```
controllers:
     resource: ../../src/Controller/
     type: annotation
```

I have routes in /config/routes.yaml

```
about:
    path:         /about
    controller:   Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\TemplateController::templateAction
    defaults:
        template: front/about.html.twig
        ...
```

Dynamic routes in "controllers" are overriding my "static" routes.

What is the best way to load "static" routes before those in controllers.

I made it work by commenting the content in /config/routes/annotations.yaml and pasting it in the end of /config/routes.yaml but I don't feel it's the best way to do it...

Comment: what do you mean they are overriding? if you create an "/about" route in your controller, it is taken instead of the static one?

Comment: I have /{slug} in my controller and /about in routes.yaml to have a controllerless route.
/{slug} take priority over /about

Comment: imo, having a route that is 100% determined by the user is not ideal... I believe you should add something to your route (`"\something\{slug}"`), that way you won't have the issue, and the route will be clearer for everyone

Comment: Routes are loaded in the order they're imported to the kernel, you've always the opportunity to customize this order in `Kernel.php` or splitting these files (alphabetically) to guarantee the right order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It didn't want to change my url nor using the alphabetical trick as suggested in the comments.

I fixed it by changing the order of imported routes in the kernel.

Instead of:

```
protected function configureRoutes(RouteCollectionBuilder $routes)
    {
        $confDir = $this->getProjectDir().'/config';

        $routes->import($confDir.'/{routes}/*'.self::CONFIG_EXTS, '/', 'glob');
        $routes->import($confDir.'/{routes}/'.$this->environment.'/**/*'.self::CONFIG_EXTS, '/', 'glob');
        $routes->import($confDir.'/{routes}'.self::CONFIG_EXTS, '/', 'glob');
    }
```

I

```
protected function configureRoutes(RouteCollectionBuilder $routes)
        {
            $confDir = $this->getProjectDir().'/config';
            # routes loaded in routes.yaml
            $routes->import($confDir.'/{routes}'.self::CONFIG_EXTS, '/', 'glob');
            # routes loaded in routes/annotations.yaml
            $routes->import($confDir.'/{routes}/*'.self::CONFIG_EXTS, '/', 'glob');
            $routes->import($confDir.'/{routes}/'.$this->environment.'/**/*'.self::CONFIG_EXTS, '/', 'glob');
        }
```

Comment: Please do a debug:router command, and make sure that the catch all route is last. Like I explained, you should not use annotations for the catch all action.

Answer (score 1):

Technically this might not be enough though. Any route loaded after this will be ignored, and if you are using annotations, you have to put this action in the last action of the last controller sorted alphabetically.

Configure this route in yml, and put it at the end of routes.yml.

This route will be the last to execute (performance hit), and it will catch all requests, so make sure you throw 404-s properly.

(Am I right in assuming that the client wants to be able to configure routes completely? eg CMS pages? Had that situation a couple of times)

Answer (score 0):

You can avoid changing the kernel logic by putting the controller with annotations after the static route in routes.xml:

```yaml
browserconfig:
    path: /browserconfig.xml
    controller: Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\TemplateController::templateAction
    defaults:
        template: browserconfig.xml.twig

app_document:
    resource: App\Controller\DocumentController
    type: annotation
```